# TypeInfoResolver Modifier doesn't resolve correct type - it resolves base type instead of real type

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I have difficulty replacing Newtonsoft's ContractResolver with System.Text.Json TypeInfoResolver Modifier.

I have a ContractResolver that is responsible for serializing only specific properties:

```
public sealed class BaseExceptionContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    public BaseExceptionContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
    }

    protected override IList<Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Type in Newtonsoft.Json: {type}");
        return !type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseException)) ? base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization) : base.CreateProperties(typeof(BaseException), memberSerialization).Where(IsExceptionProperty).ToList();
    }

    private bool IsExceptionProperty(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property)
    {
        if (property.PropertyName == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return property.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Type), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
               || property.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Details), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
               || property.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Description), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

I've created similar logic using System.Text.Json:

```
public static  class Modifiers
{
    public static void OnlyBaseExceptionProperties(System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Type in System.Text.Json: {typeInfo.Type}");

        if (!typeInfo.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseException)))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Name.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Type), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || property.Name.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Details), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || property.Name.Equals(nameof(BaseException.Description), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = static (_, _) => true;
            }
            else
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = static (_, _) => false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm using it in my test application:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseExceptionContractResolver = new BaseExceptionContractResolver();

        var newtonsoftSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
            { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, ContractResolver = baseExceptionContractResolver };

        var textJsonSettings = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            WriteIndented = true,
            TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
            {
                Modifiers = { Modifiers.OnlyBaseExceptionProperties }
            }
        };

        Exception exception1 = new ValidationException("Test");
        var exception2 = new ValidationException("Test");

        var s1e1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception1, newtonsoftSettings);
        var s2e1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exception1, textJsonSettings);

        Console.WriteLine(s1e1 == s2e1);

        var s1e2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception2, newtonsoftSettings);
        var s2e2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exception2, textJsonSettings);

        Console.WriteLine(s1e2 == s2e2);

            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
False
True
```

When I specify the type as `Exception` the type passed to `CreateProperty` in ContractResolver is correct:
[image]
but the type passed to my modifier is incorrect:
[image]

when I use var then everything works as expected, but I want to use this inside my global exception handler logic, so the correct type should be resolved.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in TypeInfoResolver or in my code and how to fix it.
I've created a simple project that shows this behavior:https://github.com/Misiu/JsonSerializerTests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that for:

```cs
var s2e1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exception1, textJsonSettings);
```

Generic [`Serialize<TValue>(TValue, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-serialize-1(-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) method is used which does not perform actual type check and uses the generic parameter to determine serialization type, i.e. `GetTypeInfo<TValue>(options)`. You can workaround with changing call to something like:

```cs
var s2e1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exception1, exception1.GetType(), textJsonSettings);
// or
var s2e1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize((object)exception1, textJsonSettings);
```

Or looking into [polymorphic type serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0), or creating custom serializer for exception:

```cs
var textJsonSettings = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // ...
    Converters = { new ExceptionConverter() }
};

public sealed class ExceptionConverter : JsonConverter<System.Exception>
{
    public override System.Exception? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var newOpts = CopyWithoutConverter(options, typeof(System.Exception));

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<System.Exception>(ref reader, newOpts);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, System.Exception value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is BaseException be)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, be, options);
        }
        else
        {
            var newOpts = CopyWithoutConverter(options, typeof(System.Exception));
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, newOpts);
        }
    }

    static JsonSerializerOptions CopyWithoutConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
            {
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        return copy;
    }
}
```

Also I modified the modifier a bit:

```
public static void OnlyBaseExceptionProperties(System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
{
    if (!typeInfo.Type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(BaseException)))
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(typeInfo.Type);
    var names = new[]
    {
        nameof(BaseException.Type),
        nameof(BaseException.Details),
        nameof(BaseException.Description),
    };

    foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
    {
        if (names.Contains(property.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = static (_, _) => true;
        }
        else
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = static (_, _) => false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: option with adding type to Serialize works, I'll check custom Converter later. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for all the updates. I used the Modifier solution with an extra type property. It would look cleaner if I could use `propery.ShouldSerialize = true`, but sadly we must use a predicate. P.S. I've also added an extra check to my modifier: `if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object) return;`